# How to give each WSL distro a distinct IP address?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtual-machines, windows-subsystem-for-linux

How to give each WSL distro a distinct IP address, and then connect to those IP addresses via Windows?

I was curious if its possible to setup two different ubuntu distributions using WSL and somehow assign a unique IP address to each one of them, and then finally to write a winsock program under windows that can commute with each running WSL virtual machine using the IP address assigned to them.

Is it possible to configure a static IP address that is unique to each distro, and accessible from windows?

Comment: Surely not possible using WSL1, can't tell about WSL2. How about using proper VMs? WSL2 is a kind of VM actually.

Comment: Unlike WSL1, WSL2 has a virtualized ethernet adapter with its own unique IP address.